# imshow in opencv with python is not interactive

Tags: python, jupyter, opencv, imshow

I am facing a bit of an issue with imshow(). I am displaying an image using the following code:

```
cv2.namedWindow("image", cv2.WINDOW_GUI_EXPANDED)
cv2.imshow("image", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[(displayed window)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBWD3.png)

But the window only displays the image, it does not show RGB information or coordinates, and it does not zoom in/out. I have watched tutorials and it seems that people can view all of these things as soon as the window pops up. I tried searching to see if anyone else had a similar problem, and I only found an answer saying that I should check if my OpenCV version is 3.4+. My version is 3.4.1, so it should work fine, but it isn't. Can someone help me with this?

Thanks.

Comment: What you mention is the Qt interface, which is not the default one. Last time I installed openCV you had to compile from source to enable it, but it may have changed with the last versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternatively, you can also simply use matplotlib library to have zoom/coordinates/RGB features:

```
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('lena.png')
plt.imshow(img)
plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.show()
```

With Jupyter, you can try:

```
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('lena.png')
%matplotlib qt
plt.imshow(img)
plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.show()
```

You may need few dependencies.

Comment: @Nour I did not realise you were using jupyter notebook. Did you try %matplotlib qt before plot?

Comment: I tried it just now! It's working! Thank you very much. But it is acting a little weird. It shows gray images in green-ish colors, and colored images in purple-ish colors. Is it a matter of adjusting the colormap?

Comment: @Nour, it is possible. I would try that e.g. try cmap='gray' or other settings.